# Detect whether browser is IE 7 or lower?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So i am going to add a redirect to my site to toss every one that is using ie 7 or lower off to a different page and came up with this JavaScript, but it seems to have stopped working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for MSIE x.x;
  var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
   if (ieversion<=8)
    window.location = "ie.html" 
   }
   window.location = "main.html"
</script>
```

Comment: If you're testing for IE **7** or lower then your code should say `<=7`, not `<=8`. (Beyond that, i think p.campbell gave a good answer.)

Comment: [How do I detect Opera/Safari/IE?](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#detectBrowser) Browser sniffing using the UA string is a sure sign of poor site design. People have been writing cross-browser web sites using feature or capability detection that accommodates every browser from IE 5 up for years, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is always resulting to having gone to `main.html`. Even when the code falls into `<8`, you'll fall out of the `if` into setting to `main`.

Consider refactoring by either:

- setting a `return` after setting to `ie`.

or

```
var redir="main.html";
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent))
{ 
   var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1);
   if (ieversion<=8)
   {
      redir = "ie.html";
   }
}
window.location = redir;
```

Answer (score 9):

Check out [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#syntax).

So you can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--[if (!IE)|(gt IE 7)]>
      window.location = "ie.html" 
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      window.location = "main.html"
    <![endif]-->
</script>
```

Comment: i would do that but i am trying to use something slightly more elegant than IE conditional comments.

Comment: @ellisgeek you're exchanging reliability for "elegance" by ignoring this answer. UA sniffing is very brittle and could very well backfire for you.

Comment: Not sure what's so inelegant about conditional comments.  They work.

Comment: The files are the wrong way round and non-IE browsers will not execute either statement. However, conditional comments is the way to go.

Comment: conditional comments only work within HTML, I have no JS within HTML, they are in external files. Conditional comments are the worst option ever.

Comment: @mare, I disagree.  There are solutions that are way worse and often break with browser or JS library version upgrades.  You can have 100% of your JS in external files and still use conditional comments to render certain metadata elements that your external JS reads.  I'm not saying it's the best solution, but it's not a bad one.  Where there's a will, there's a way.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Conditional comments (as suggested by @Kon) are the way to go. Here's a working implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ie7OrLower = false;
</script>

<!--[if lte IE 7]><script type="text/javascript">
   ie7OrLower = true;
</script><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = ie7OrLower ? "ie.html" : "main.html";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test it with this regular expression: `(MSIE\ [0-7]\.\d+)`

Here is a JavaScript example on how to use it:

```
if (/(MSIE\ [0-7]\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Quirks Mode's BrowserDetect.js for my browser detection needs. Check it out - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Once you've referenced the .js file, you can access lots of information:

```
//Browser Name
BrowserDetect.browser
//Browser Version
BrowserDetect.version
//Operating system
BrowserDetect.OS
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the examples at http://www.ie6nomore.com/