# Making the application browser specific

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, browser, authentication

The tested and supported platform for my application is Windows based computer with IE as browser. If the browser which the user uses is not Internet Explorer then my application should not permit the user to log in.

How do I do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can check for user-agent though it can be easily faked, but its a general approach.

Comment: You do know that internet explorer has only 30% market share. Perhaps do a bit more testing.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: This makes me very, very sad.

Comment: Would it be so hard to test it with some other browsers?

Comment: Not so. But my client's requirements says so. I should deliver it exactly what they want

Comment: You know if it works in IE its very likely to work in others, perhaps detect if IE and then produce a warning if not. That might be a little more of a proportional response.

Comment: Richard how do I detect if it is IE? thanks

Comment: AY89 thanks for ur help. detected the browser with user agent. The next problem is to redirect it to an error page

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104109/detect-whether-browser-is-ie-7-or-lower

Comment: @suresh, it's probably a good idea to inquire *why* your client wants that or believes they want it. Some clients are merely uninformed and, if they knew better, would not stipulate this requirement.

Comment: @suresh if not ie , then in script give document.location=<errorpage.jsp>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you *really* want to detect the usage of IE (although in most cases detecting browser supported features would be better), you can check if the User Agent is Internet Explorer, and if not, disable login.

In the below code snippet from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), `getInternetExplorerVersion()` returns `-1` is the browser is not IE, and returns the version if the browser is IE. Based upon the value of this function, you can decide whether or not to enable login.

**Example**

```
var IEdetected = getInternetExplorerVersion();
if (IEdetected == -1){
     // disable login
}
```

**IE Detection Code from MSDN**

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
function checkVersion()
{
  var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

  if ( ver > -1 )
  {
    if ( ver >= 8.0 ) 
      msg = "You're using a recent copy of Internet Explorer."
    else
      msg = "You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.";
  }
  alert( msg );
}
```

Browser Detection Code from MSDN Article [Detecting Windows Internet Explorer More Effectively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)